# Stored procedure to calculate path of tree

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, tree

I'm new about the world of SQL programming but I have to do this procedure.

The user gives me a primary key of a stored tree, of a start vertex and finish vertex. I calculate the path between these two vertex and return the result like a list: attribute1="value", attribute2="value"...

The assumption are, the user has to give a path that is in the same sub-branch of tree, in fact I don't check the possibility of this error. The security is not a requirements but the performance is. For this reason I'm asking your expert opinions about my implementation of this procedure.

The DB is made in this way:

```
Tree(pk, ....); vertex(pk,parent,...,fk_tree); attr_def (pk, name);
attr_usage(pk, fk_vert, fk_attr, value, next);
```

I know there are other better implementation of this database but I have got also time constraint, so I think this solution is fast to implement.

Now if you look the tables, you can notice there are variable attributes between  the vertex in different trees, but the nodes in the same tree, have identical number of nodes. So I thought to slide the number of attributes like a list with the columns "a_usage.next".

In this function I'm going to sum all the attributes of vertex that I meet during my path. I start from the finish vertex to the start vertex  through the parent columns.

After these premises, have you got some advice in order to find some error and make my stored procedure faster?

Here's my code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[calc_path]
    @tree_pk int, 
    @vertexa int,
    @vertexb int,
    @result nvarchar(255) OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

    declare @na int
    declare @sp int
    declare @ind int = 1

    select @na=T.natt, @sp=T.split from [dbo].Tree as T where T.id_tree=@tree_pk
    --nella tabella result tengo traccia per ogni attributi i valori sommati quando esco dal ciclo
    --con un cursore riesco li concateno in una stringa
    create table #result
    (
        attr_id int not null,
        attr_name varchar(10) not null,     
    )

     insert into #result(attr_id, attr_name)
         (select attrdef.id_attr, attrdef.name from attrdef)

    alter table #result add value int default 0

     --lavoro solo sui vertici dui quel determinato albero
    declare @cmd nvarchar (max)
    set @cmd = N'create view vert_tree
    as
    select * from vertex where vertex.tree_id ='+@tree_pk
    exec (@cmd)

declare @at int
declare @parent int
declare @t_value int
declare @t_value2 int
declare @t_next int
declare @t_attr int

while @vertexa = @vertexb
BEGIN
    --seleziono il vertice b dalla vista precedentemente creata
    select @parent = vert_tree.par, @at = vert_tree.attr from vert_tree where vert_tree.vertex_id = @vertexb
    --scorro la lista dei attributi
    while @na = @ind
    begin
    --ricerco l'attributo i-esimo del vertex b
        select @t_value = a_usage.value, @t_next = a_usage.next, @t_attr = a_usage.n_att
                 from a_usage where a_usage.attr = @at and a_usage.vertex = @vertexb
        --imposto il prossimo attributo
        set @at = @t_next
        --prendo il campo value dell'attributo specifico e lo sommo con quello corrente
        select @t_value2 = @result.value from #result where #result.attr_id = @t_attr
        set @t_value2 += @t_value
        --Rimetto il valore modificato nella tabella
        update #result set #result.value = @t_value2 where #result.attr_id = @t_attr
        set @ind += 1
    end
    set @ind = 1
    SET @vertexb = @parent
END
--Return the results from culcalating path
DECLARE @app nvarchar(max)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT attr_name, value FROM #result

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT From cure INTO @app
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @result += @app+', '
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @app
END
CLOSE cur
drop table #result
RETURN @result
END
GO
```

Thanks for any good help!

Comment: What error are you getting when you run the code you posted?

Comment: yuck; if you can change the table structure I'd go with `hierarchyid` and a recursive CTE (common table expression)